# Memory Management : arrays and dynamic allocation with new operator

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, assignment-operator

Memory Management : arrays and dynamic allocation with new operator

Q. In terms of Memory Management, what error does occur?

```
class String
{
public:
 String(const char right[]);
 String& operator= (const String& right);
 int length() const;
private:
 char* buffer;
 int len;
}

int String::length() const {return len;}

String::String(const char right[])
{
 len = 0;
 while (right[len] != '\0')
   len++;
 buffer = new char[len+1];
 for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
   buffer[i] = right[i];
 buffer[len] = '\0';
}

String& String::operator= (const String& right)
{
 if (this != &right)
  { 
    delete[] buffer;
    len = right.length();
    char* buffer = new char[len + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
      buffer[i] = right[i];
    buffer[len] = '\0';
  }
  return *this;
}
```

Answer.
I have no clue... Could you help me?
This one seems ok too.
new and it is also deleted.
Where is the memory leak?

Please let me know.
Thanks,

Comment: What's your question? What error are you getting?

Comment: In addition to all the answers, you should always remember one thing: if you use operator `new`, you should use operator `delete` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 issues with your code.

1. Your assignment operator has the following line: `char* buffer = new char[len + 1];` This is declaring a new pointer variable and not using the class member. This will allocate memory to a pointer that then goes out of scope and can never be deleted and will be a memory leak and make your class not function.
2. The lack of a destructor means that your class leaks memory. Your destructor is responsible for freeing the memory that your are allocating with `new[]`.
3. The lack of a copy constructor means that your String class cannot be used in many situations including in an STL container. The STL containers require that types have a public copy constructor, assignment operator and desctructor.
4. You are not enforcing your class invariants in the face of exceptions. The goal is to make your class [exception safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety). In the changes I made I tried to achieve the strong exception guarantee and conserve the class state in the face of exceptions. Considering exception safety is an important aspect of creating your own classes - especially library classes such as String.

Here's the code that attempts fixes all of those issues. To keep the code short I am putting the implementation into the class rather than separating it. Of course, in real code you should use std::string.

```
class String
{
public:
    String() : len(0), buffer(nullptr)
    {}

    String(const char right[]) : len(0), buffer(nullptr)
    {
        if(!right)
            return;

        int temp_len = strlen(right);
        buffer = new char[temp_len+1];
        len = temp_len; // only set the length after the allocation succeeds
        strcpy(buffer, right);
    }

    // a copy constructor is essential for this class
    String(const String& right) : len(0), buffer(nullptr)
    {
        String temp(right.buffer);
        swap(temp);
    }

    // must have a destructor to avoid leaks
    ~String()
    {
        if(buffer) // only delete if it has been allocated
            delete[] buffer;
    }

    String& operator= (const String& right)
    {
        String temp(right.buffer);
        swap(temp);
        return *this;
    }

    int length() const
    {
        return len;
    }
private:
    void swap(String& rhs)
    {
        std::swap(buffer, rhs.buffer);
        std::swap(len, rhs.len);
    }
    char* buffer;
    int len;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a constructor which allocates the pointer member(*infact all constructors of your class should do that*) and destructor which deallocates it.

Also, You need to provide a copy constructor which performs a deep copy of the pointer member.

```
String::String(const String& obj)
{
   ....
}
```

Good Read:
[What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Also, `String` is an awful name for a class especially since there exists a `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

[Rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29): if a class defines a destructor or a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator, it probably has to define all three.

Your code vioaltes this rule by not providing a destructor and a copy constructor while providing a copy assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

When your String objects are destroyed, the default constructor is called since you did not define one. The default destructor will not delete[] your char array for you, you must declare and define a destructor to do this.

Also, you will find that using strcpy()/strncpy() is much faster than a simple loop to copy each char. (at least when compiling with GCC).